# conditional map in normal mode?

Tags: vim, dictionary, conditional-statements

Is it possible in vim to do a conditional map, in normal mode?
I've seen it for insert mode.
I want to remap gq, depending on the outcome of a function.
Something like:

```
nnoremap gq if(g:set_formatprg()) | gq | else | = | endif
```

Notice that `g:set_formatprg()` will not always have the same value, so it **cannot** be replaced by

```
if(!g:set_formatprg()) | nnoremap gq = | endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An expression map makes it easy

```
nnoremap <expr> gq g:set_formatprg() ? 'gq' : '='
```

For more help see

```
:h map-expression
```